# Unity android build not working as expected

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I recently made a 3d game in unity. It is a clone of https://livegame.show/games/tower/

It works fine in unity editor,but when I built for android, it doesn't work as expected. 
In my game, once the game is over, a 'Game Over' text appears on the screen. Then, on click, I restart everything.
I use:
`SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene");`

But in mobile, on click, the game over text doesn't vanish. Also the tile falls down (due to useGravity of rigidbody enabled, whole it should be disabled on start). But the number of tiles and score reset to zero.

In editor there is no such behaviour. It is fine. 
The problems, seem to have nothing to do with android. What do I need to check then?

Comment: Have you check in File > Build Settings, that your scene is selected?
Also, have you renamed your scene?

Comment: I didn't rename the default scene. Does that matter?

Comment: I was just wondering because `SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene");` relies on the name of the scene. Also have you checked in File > Build Settings like I said?

Comment: Yeah. In build scenes, there was no scene, so I added SampleScene. But  still there is same problem.

Comment: When I open build settings, I get this error at bottom: `Unity editor.PackageManager.Requests.SearchRequest failed with error: UnityEditor.PackageManager.Error`.  Maybe this has something to do with the problem